# На сервере вместо кириллического символа «і» получаю «?». В чем проблема?

Tags: node.js, javascript, express

Здравствуйте!

При сабмите формы методом GET на сервере я получаю параметры формы через `req.query`. Но все буквы "і" в кириллице у меня заменяются на знаки вопроса "?".
Как быть? Писать в `value` латиницей? А может, можно как-то не заменять на латиницу, а все-таки передавать в `value` кириллицей?

Спасибо!

**Обновление**

Повсюду, где это возможно, стоит UTF-8. Теперь я уже разобрался, проблема в самой системе (У меня Windows). Там даже в консоле "і" не отображается, я поменял шрифт на Luicida Console, и все заработало. Но этот метод не помогает у WebStorm.

Comment: А какой charset у страницы?

Comment: Нужно чаще ставить utf-8 в параметрах, иначе все будет очень плохо.